# iTextSharp 5.3.3:Insert PushbuttonField in PDF and SetAction

Tags: itext

I want to create PushButton in PDF-document and set Action (GoToLocalPage):

```
PushButton:=New PushbuttonField(stamper.writer, New Rectangle(300, 300,330,330),"Text");
PushButton.Image:=img;
PushButton.ProportionalIcon:=True;
PushButton.Layout:=PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_ONLY;
PushButton.Field.Action:=PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(2, New PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT), stamper.Writer);
stamper.AddAnnotation(PushButton.Field,5);
```

As a result, the Action is not working. What am I doing wrong?

In all the examples written: PushButton.GetFields().SetAction(...). But in iTextSharp 5.3.3 method GetFields does not exist...

I tried:

```
Action:=PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(2, New PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT), stamper.Writer);

PushButton.Field.SetAdditionalActions(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.D, Action);
```

But it's does not working too..

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it :

```
PdfAnnotation pushbuttonAnn = PushButton.Field;  
pushbuttonAnn.Action:=PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(2, New PdfDestination PdfDestination.FIT), stamper.Writer);  
stamper.AddAnnotation(pushbuttonAnn,5);
```